# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' - IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2012

I am attempting to do an install on Windows Server 2012. I've set the .Net Framework version to the following:

[image]

When I navigate to the site, I get a runtime notification telling me to turn `customeErrors` off. So, naturally, I go to my web.config and look under the `system.web` node. However, I see the following errors highlighted by the `targetFramework` attribute

[image]

Both errors read

> the 'targetFramework' attribute is not declared.

Now, to make this more confusing, I decide to log into the Event Viewer on this server, and I see a number of ASP 2.0 errors related specifically to this site (essentially the errosr logged when I tried to access the site).

If I click on any of the messages I see the following error

[image]

I've double checked that .Net 4.5 is installed on the computer, however with the multiple error messages I'm not sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Bonehead move here.... Had the website set to run under the wrong app pool. The web site was set to run under the default app pool, which was run under ASP .NET 2.0.